# track the count of incomming sms

Tags: android, database, sms

I have my question in the following link  [SmS count not increasing. message id is constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202850/sms-count-not-increasing-message-id-is-constant)  any one please answer. thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmS count not increasing. message id is constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202850/sms-count-not-increasing-message-id-is-constant)

Comment: @MitchWheat duplicate but that answer is unanswered.

Comment: @Me and We: that's not how this site works....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri sms_content = Uri.parse("content://sms");
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(sms_content, null,null, null, null);
```

And now you can work with Cursor `c`. like `c.getCount()` for total Sms

There are more options like `content://sms/sent` or `content://sms/inbox`.

And don't forget to Give Permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested to track only incoming SMS it would be better to use a Broadcast with action `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` that will track it better than `ContentObserver`. [**Try this one.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)